# Long Press Event in Qt

Tags: qt, events

I just want to know if there is a long press event available in **Qt**
The module im working on currently requires long press. I have seen long press in C7 for uninstalling.

The button click event and the button press event gives the same result right?

alfah

Comment: Are you talking about key presses (keyboard) or clicks (mouse)?

Comment: Is this desktop, symbian or something else? The answer may be different in each case.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. Yes, Im talking about key presses. I want to know to if there is a way to implement long key press. Ie if i click the button once it does an activity, if i press it twice it does another activity. Now I want to press and hold for some time to start yet another activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at Qt's [gesture framework](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/gestures-overview.html),
The gesture you are after would be [QTapAndHoldGesture](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtapandholdgesture.html) then I think.

Comment: Sorry about not being clear. Yes, Im talking about key presses. I want to know to if there is a way to implement long key press. Ie if i click the button once it does an activity, if i press it twice it does another activity. Now I want to press and hold for some time to start yet another activity.

Comment: FYI: Second link is dead, and ... Qt4.x in 2017? What about just doing this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gestures-overview.html and this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtapandholdgesture.html

Comment: breadcrumbs: QT Quick 5 has the [`pressAndHold` signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#pressAndHold-signal)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
```

and

```
keyReleaseEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
```

for handle long_press_event

Answer (score 2):

The *quick*, *easy* and *old fashioned* way, if you don't want to use that gesture stuff goes a little something like this:

In **header** declare a millisecond time stamp to hold the time of last press.

```
private:
    // Remembers the point in time when mouse button went down
    quint64 mLastPressTime=0;
    // Pressing and holding for one full second constitutes a "longpress", set whatever value in milliseconds you want here.
    static const quint64 MY_LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD=1000; 
protected:
    // Declare that we are overriding QWidget's events for mouse press and release
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
signals:
    // Our custom signal to emit once a longpress is detected.
    void longPressEvent(QMouseEvent *);
```

In **source** define the mouse press and release handlers like so:

```
void MyClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Remeber last time mousr was pressed
    mLastPressTime=QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
}

void MyClass::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Calculate for how long the button has been pressed upon release
    const quint64 pressTime = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() - mLastPressTime;
    // The press time exceeds our "threshold" and this constitutes a longpress
    if( pressTime > MY_LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD){
        // We pass the original mouse event in case it is useful (it contains all sorts of goodies like mouse posittion, which button was pressed etc).
        emit longPressEvent(event);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I did not compile this code, except in the built in compiler in my head which has a lot of non-traditional extensions.